# Unable to change to previous io input

Tags: lua

i am currently trying to make a small script that temporarily changes the io input to a file and then back to the previews input. i have tried searching for solutions and all i found was this from lua.org

```
    local temp = io.input()   -- save current file
    io.input("newinput")      -- open a new current file
    ...                       -- do something with new input
    io.input():close()        -- close current file
    io.input(temp)            -- restore previous current file
```

however when i attempt this i get this error
`Bad Argument #1 (string or file expected, got table):`
i am relatively new to lua so any help would be outstanding

Thanks.

Comment: What is `temp`?

Comment: Works fine for me.  Can't reproduce the error.  What line# the error is generated at?

Comment: If you tried that code in the interactive interpreter, try removing `local` or putting the whole code inside a `do...end` block.